# Increment a date on a field

Tags: javascript, date

I have a field with the date of the day (format: YYYY/MM/DD)

```
<input type='text' name='date_debut' size='15' value='"; echo date("Y-m-d"); echo "' />
```

Next to this field I would like to add a button to increment the day only (something simple :) )

For example
2011/02/13 and when I click on the button I get
2011/02/14, then 2011/02/15, then 2011/02/16, then 2011/02/17...

Is there a javascript code to do that in an easy way?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

```
<input id="ddBox" value="2009-2-28" />
<button onclick="addDate()">add</button>


function addDate() {
    var inputBox = document.getElementById("ddBox");
    var nDate = new Date(inputBox.value);
    nDate.setDate(nDate.getDate() + 1);
    inputBox.value = nDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (nDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + nDate.getDate();
}
```

If you need "02" instead of "2" in the months, for example, it is not difficult to create a function to do the padding. And remember that the months start with 0 for January.

Answer (score 1):

you can use date JavaScript library. http://www.datejs.com/. 
It can do all these task 
http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/

Answer (score 0):

you could use jQuery to achieve this. Check the following code:

**html**

```
<input type='text' name='date_debut' size='15' value='2011/02/13' /><a href="#">add one</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
var dateText = $('input').attr("value").split("/");
var date =new Date();
date.setFullYear(dateText[0],dateText[1],dateText[2]);

$('a').click(function() {
   date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
    $('input').attr('value',date.getFullYear()+'/'+date.getMonth()+'/'+date.getDate());

});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/9kVS7/1

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect
Thx so much